# Do I need to delete my buffer after sending it into boost::asio::buffer?

Tags: c++, boost, char, buffer

Sp I have a function like:

```
void WriteToUrl(const unsigned char *buf, int size)
{
boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(buf, size));
}
```

Do I need to delete buffer if I do not use it any where else? How do I need to clean after y function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood you are always the ownership of the buffer 'buf'. With synchronous operations, as ::write, you can delete the buffer as soon as ::write finish. With asynchronous operations, as ::async_write, you need to give an asynchronous completion token (a callback) which will be called when the operation has been done. The you could delete the buf in this callback.

Comment: Good answer ++, however the first sentence doesn't look complete, can you rephrase it to your meaning?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a pointer to the buffer that you could delete, even if you wanted to.

The input data from `buf` is used to construct the Boost.Asio `buffer`, and then the memory used in that construction is managed by the library.  The write call blocks until all the data is written, so I imagine the data is not copied internally (but I am not sure about that).

You should of course perform any required cleanup on the buffer you gave to the constructor (`buf`) when you are done with it.

Comment: The `buffer()` function creates a `mutable_buffer` object which is internally just a pointer to the original buffer. So no memory is copied, and it doesn't take the ownership.

Comment: @Timo - that makes sense in the context of a blocking call, thanks.